# Invalid Credentials when attempting connection to Xamarin mac Agent

Tags: ios, xamarin

I'm a brand new Xamarin User.  I'm trying to connect to my Mac Machine from my Win 10 machine. Both are on my home network.

I'm using Visual Studio 2015 community. I have all the latest Xamarin code installed. From the VS Tools Menu I selected 'IOS/Xamarin Mac Agent' to connect to my Mac Machine.

I'm being prompted for the Username and password for the Mac. I entered the correct info but the system is responding with invalid Credentials.

I'm positive that my credentials are correct and the Mac is setup to allow remote connections from any user. Don't know where to go from here. The Mac is running OS X Yosemite.

Answer (score 5):

Are you by chance using your full name as opposed to the actual user name for your Mac user account? You can find your actual account name by opening Terminal on the Mac and entering the command `whoami`. This will return your actual user name.

Otherwise I would recommend going over the connection trouble shooting guide here: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/getting_started/installation/windows/connecting-to-mac/troubleshooting/

For the issue I think you are experiencing, see item 5 in this section of the above:
https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/getting_started/installation/windows/connecting-to-mac/troubleshooting/#Troubleshooting_Remote_Login

"Make sure you are connecting to the Mac with the username rather than the Full Name. This avoids a known limitation for full names that include accented characters."

Answer (score 3):

I am also having this issue. This is what fixed it for me.

System Preferences -> Sharing -> Computer Name:

Change this to a single word "MyNameMac"

Note below you will see Remote Login: On. If it is not on turn it on on the left hand side. Then note down the login domain myname@192.168.x.y similar to this format.

After changing the computers name, back on windows 10 in visual studio. You will have a new mac shown (because you changed the name). Connect to it. Do not put @192... at the end just stick you your user name. You can also get the user name from the terminal via "whoami" open the terminal using cmd + space then typing terminal and hitting enter.

Enjoy.

Answer (score 3):

I kept having this issue, and google kept leading me to this question, but the issue wasn't the username.

So, for any future visitors, the issue for me was my custom `.zshrc` setup. So try renaming `.zshrc` to `.zshrc-off` and see if that helps.