# Visual Studio 2022 Xamarin can't pair with remote mac, "Invalid Crededentials"

Tags: macos, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I'm trying to pair Visual Studio 2022 for Windows with a remote Mac, so I can build an iOS/Xamarin app (per https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/get-started/installation/windows/connecting-to-mac/). Upon entering my Mac credentials in Visual Studio, it says "Invalid credentials. Please try again." The credentials are definitely connect - I can connect with them both over VNC and over SSH. Similar questions have been asked & answered many times in various ways, but none of the solutions seem to work:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/get-started/installation/windows/connecting-to-mac/troubleshooting says that you'll get that message if you connect using the account full name & it has accented characters. I'm connecting via username, which is just "m1".
- [Invalid Credentials when attempting connection to Xamarin mac Agent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38444933/invalid-credentials-when-attempting-connection-to-xamarin-mac-agent) suggests removing spaces from the computer name. There are none. Another answer to that question mensions a custom .zshrc setup, but that isn't applicable (the Mac is a fresh cloud instance just spun up on Scaleway).
- [xamarin unable to connect to mac - login failure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38953574/xamarin-unable-to-connect-to-mac-login-failure?rq=3) suggests that you need Xamarin.iOS installed on the Mac, but that's no longer true since VS 2019, per: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/get-started/installation/windows/connecting-to-mac/#automatic-mac-provisioning
- XCode is launched & running on the remote Mac.
- Firewall is disabled on both the Mac and Windows (note that Visual Studio can definitely see the Mac, as the credentials dialog displays the remote system's SSH fingerprint).
- I've tried clearing C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Xamarin\MonoTouch, as suggested here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36630163/136785
- I tried explicitly creating a second user & allowing them Remote Login access on the mac

This is an incomplete list of what I've tried - but after nearly 5 hours at this, I cannot make any progress past "Invalid Credentials. Please try again." Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: Is your remote Mac connected to the same network as your Windows machine? And please post detailed error log.

Comment: It's remote, over the internet (mentioned above, it's a cloud instance spun up on Scaleway). Which specific logs would be helpful? Thanks

Comment: If it's OK, please try to let them(Windows and Mac) be on the same network segment. Any error message is okay.

Comment: I don't own a physical mac, it's a cloud mac provider.